# How to detect multiple connections from the same computer with SignalR

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr

I have been tasked to develop a utility application to run tasks on a user computer from within our web app (accounting system sync., etc.). I use SignalR to communicate with both ends and it works well. However, I'd like to add a validation that the application is running on the same computer than the person invoking it from the web app.

So far I have been able to validate using the username. The utility app pass the username to the hub via SignalR, and when I invoke it from the web app, I can validate the username.

```
protected string CurrentEmployeeUsername
{
    get { return Context.User.Identity.Name; }
}

/// <summary>
/// Used to lock the dictionary for concurrent connections
/// </summary>
private static readonly object LockObject = new object();

private static Dictionary<string, string> _UtilityAppSessions;

/// <summary>
/// Keep a track of connectionId / username
/// </summary>
public static Dictionary<string, string> UtilityAppSessions
{
    get
    {
        return _UtilityAppSessions ??
               (_UtilityAppSessions = new Dictionary<string, string>());
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Joins the group for the utility app
/// </summary>
public Task JoinUtilityAppGroup(string username)
{
    lock (LockObject)
    {
        UtilityAppSessions.Add(Context.ConnectionId, username.ToUpper());
    }

    return Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, "Utility");
}

public AccountingSyncronizationOperationResult ProcessSynchronization(SynchronizationOrigin origin, string synchronizationId)
{
    // Check if we have a utility app running
    if (!UtilityAppSessions.Any())
    {
        return new AccountingSyncronizationOperationResult()
        {
            Success = false,
            ErrorMessage = "No utility application is available to process the synchronization."
        };
    }

    // Make sure the user have the utility app running with their username
    if (UtilityAppSessions.ContainsValue(CurrentEmployeeUsername.ToUpper()))
    {
        // The user is running the utility app on his computer, start sync.
        Clients.Client(UtilityAppSessions.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value == CurrentEmployeeUsername).Key).doSynchronization(new {Origin = origin, SynchronizationId = synchronizationId});

        return new AccountingSyncronizationOperationResult()
        {
            Success = true
        };
    }

    return new AccountingSyncronizationOperationResult()
    {
        Success = false,
        ErrorMessage = "The utility app needs to be running with your username and on your computer to process synchronization."
    };

}
```

This works, however if the user is logged on another computer, it will call the utility app on the computer where it is running, not on the computer where the web app is. 
Obviously the ConnectionIds are different (between the web app and the utility app) because I have two distinct connections, so unless I'm missing something this won't help me.

It should not be a problem in our app because everyone is supposed to have their own username, but I'd like this feature to be more solid if I can.

Thanks to anyone for input

Comment: May I ask what would you do if you detect that a user is using your app in multiple browsers from the same machine?  You may want to consider UX.  If you disconnect one of the sessions at random, it may frustrate the user. Don't want to create problems that don't exist.

Comment: I don't see this being a problem, the detection is done for the utility app. If the user is logged on two different browsers from the same machine, they will connect to the hub when they invoke utility app (from a button or something in the web app).  Once in the hub server method "ProcessSynchronization" this is where I need to know if the utility app is running on the same computer, wether or not they are logged multiple times in the web app.

Comment: To clarify, consider the following : 
Utility app running on Computer A, User A on computer B invokes the method. It needs to fail because he is not on computer A. User A on computer A should work.

Comment: User B invokes a method using Computer A and that should fail because Computer A can only be used by User A?

Comment: Maybe you could get the clients mac address and send it with the request. On the web app, you would need something like a java applet or activex control to get access to this. Maybe you could also save a cookie with a randomly generated number and try to access the cookie from your utility app (don't know if this is possible, but could be worth a try).